# Bootstrap rounded top right corner

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap list-group-flush to display a left vertical nav.

I want to have the top left corner rounded. `class="rounded-top"` works, but `class="rounded-top-left"`, or `class="rounded top-left"` doesn't do anything?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always create your own global classes. For example:

```
.rounded-top-left-1 {
    border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
}
.rounded-top-right-1 {
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}
.rounded-bottom-left-1 {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
}
.rounded-bottom-right-1 {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it!

Comment: in the future though, the values (`1rem`) might change based on the bootstrap version or incase you're compiling your own version of bootstrap ( `SCSS` ) , i would go for a different approach: using `rounded-top` ( just for the top corners ) / `border-4` (when needed different size) and then remove corners i don't want with `border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;` this way - i maintain the style structure with bootstrap and not playing with values on my the side

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs for Bootstrap 4.3 there are no utility classes to only round *one* corner: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/borders/#border-radius. If you want that class you'll have to write it yourself.

I just quickly browsed through Bootstrap 3.4 and 4.2.1. Version 3.4 doesn't have any border radius classes and 4.2 has fewer options, so this isn't something you can fix by switching to a different version.

Comment: Yeah it's a shame they don't do it. I created it in CSS - see below. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 5

rounded

rounded-top

rounded-bottom

rounded-start

rounded-end

rounded-circle

rounded-pill

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on using Bootstrap's own default code and used the following CSS:

```
#corner1 {
            border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        }

<a href="home" id="corner1" class="list-group-item">Link here</a>
```

UPDATE: Looks like Bootstrap doesn't allow for rounding of a single corner https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/borders/

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own class like:

```
.border-upper-radius {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }  
  .border-downer-radius {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a combination of Bootstrap classes as of v5.

`class="rounded-top-3 rounded-end-0"` would round the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

**Round then Un-round Solution**

Late to the party, but here is an answer to help any future round-corner-seekers.

If you only need to round the top right corner, you can round the top corners, the un-round the left corners:

```
<div class="rounded-top-4 rounded-start-0" />
```

This should leave you with a single top right rounded corner.